# C# Swagger\Swashbuckle Odata Web Api 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

Need some help. I've got swashbuckle\swagger working along with my webApi 2\Odata solution. However, I'm getting my routes for Gets and Deletes duplicated on the swagger display. It seems like swagger is interpreting my custom OData route and my web Api routes as separate end points.

What my routes look like in the controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[ODataRoute("Service(ServiceName={serviceName}, Version={version})")]
public IHttpActionResult Get([FromODataUri]string serviceName, [FromODataUri] int version)

[HttpDelete]
[ODataRoute("Service(ServiceName={serviceName}, Version={version})")]
public IHttpActionResult Delete([FromODataUri]string serviceName, [FromODataUri]int version)
```

Notice the only difference in the signature generated by swagger is that in one case `serviceName` is in (`ServiceName='{ServiceName}'`) in the other it's not (`ServiceName={ServiceName}`) Any ideas? Suggestions?

What I'm seeing in Swagger:

[image]

Comment: Amy Your idea, simply moves the http actions into their own tag. This doesn't impact the signature of the endpoints. I did try it though :) I'm wondering if the issue with swagger display isn't related to the odata route tag having 2 parameters in it? Unfortunately this is required as the entity object has a multi part key, being serviceName and version.....